# NestJS authGuard dosent works

Tags: javascript, express, authentication, nestjs

I'm implementing `@nestjs/passport` ('jwt') and using (exactly like in the instructions) the `@UseGuards(AuthGuard())` decorator but i'm getting the  following exception:

> common_1.Optional is not a function

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

Dependencies:

> "@nestjs/common": "^5.0.0",
>
> ```
> "@nestjs/core": "^5.0.0",
> "@nestjs/cqrs": "^5.1.1",
> "@nestjs/jwt": "^0.2.0",
> "@nestjs/mongoose": "^5.1.0",
> "@nestjs/passport": "^5.1.0",
> "@nestjs/swagger": "^2.4.4",
> "@nestjs/typeorm": "^5.2.2",
> "automapper-ts": "^1.9.0",
> "config": "^2.0.1",
> "fastify-formbody": "^2.0.0",
> "lodash": "^4.17.10",
> "mongodb": "^3.1.6",
> "mongoose": "^5.2.9",
> "mysql": "^2.16.0",
> "nestjs-rmq": "^0.1.3",
> "nestjs-typegoose": "^5.0.1",
> "passport": "^0.4.0",
> "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
> "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
> "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
> "typegoose": "^5.4.0",
> "typeorm": "^0.2.7",
> "typescript": "^2.6.2",
> ```

Comment: Can you add your package.json dependencies? Have you tried deleting node_modules and running npm install?

Comment: Hey.
Yes I tried to delete node_modules.. 
I added the dependencies to the question.. thanks!!

Comment: All the necessary packages are installed. You can try running `npm update` since some versions are a bit outdated. I've just set up an empty project with the jwt module and it works for me. So for further investigation, you need to add (the relevant parts) of your code or a repository to reproduce this with.

Comment: Amazing....npm update did the trick!! thank you!!!!

Comment: Glad it's working for you. :-) If you're problem is solved consider accepting an answer so others know the question has been answered.

Answer (score 3):

The dependencies are out of date. Try running `npm update`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I badly understand the question, but to use a guard, you can give a guard instance or give the class and let nest create the instance,  a guard is **not a function*

**@UseGuards(AuthGuard())**  should be :
**@UseGuards(new AuthGuard())**
or 
**@UseGuards(AuthGuard)**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use old dependencies.

install npm g **npm-check**

RUN npm-check -u

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check

Answer (score 0):

dependencies problem

try this :

$ sudo npm install -g npm-check

$ npm-check -u